fetch key and value from a super field in redshift
I have a super field that holds JSON formatted data -
** {
"awsRegion": "us-west-2",
"dynamodb": {
"ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1712584702997808,
"Keys": {
"prospectId": {
"S": "string_1"
}
},
"NewImage": {
"prospectName": {
"S": "perform-test_Ram"
},
"gaSessionId": {
"S": "1980117787.1628661599"
}
},
"SizeBytes": 467,
"ApproximateCreationDateTimePrecision": "MICROSECOND"
},
"eventSource": "aws:dynamodb"
} **
I want to extract the JSON value string prospectId,prospectName,gaSessionId I tried converting this field to varchar and the result is empty. I also tried converting to JSON_serialize and then to varchar and still the results are blank. Any help on how to fix this?

If this column (col) is of type super you just need to navigate to the field you want using '.' notation.  Like the below query but since you have uppercase field names you need to set Redshift to case sensitive as well:
SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier TO true;

SELECT col.dynamodb."Keys"."prospectId"."S" as prospectid
FROM <table>;

Note the use of double quotes when an uppercase character is in a column / field identifier.

Wow, Thanks , It worked for me. Kudos.
But we are providing exact keys with proper cases still we need
SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier TO true;

I face issue while creating metallized view
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test_sch."new_vw" AUTO REFRESH YES AS
SELECT approximate_arrival_timestamp,
JSON_PARSE(kinesis_data) as data,
kinesis_data.dynamodb."Keys"."Id"."S" as prospectId  ,
kinesis_data.dynamodb."NewImage"."Name"."S" as prospectName,
kinesis_data.dynamodb."NewImage"."SessionId"."S" as gaSessionId
from kds_schema."test-stream-dev"
WHERE CAN_JSON_PARSE(kinesis_data);

kinesis_data is varchar and data is super, so you cannot reference the super fields by the varchar name.  You need to use "data".  I also believe that you are going to need to move the JSON_PARSE() and CAN_JSON_PARSE() to a subquery or CTE.  As if I remember correctly Redshift will need this level of SELECT to be able to use the fields but try it and see.

SET both parameters to TRUE
SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier to TRUE;
SET enable_case_sensitive_super_attribute to TRUE;
